# Fastlane Tests Failing with libXCTestSwiftSupport.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins, fastlane

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been fighting for a few weeks on and off to get my unit tests running as part of my build pipeline with Jenkins and Fastlane.

When I run them through Fastlane locally, everything is fine. I run `fastlane unit_tests` and everything compiles, simulator launches, and tests run.

When I run them on the build pipeline, after the simulator launches and the first test should execute, I see an error.

I don't understand what is missing here. I would have thought the development build that fastlane creates with the `scan` option would be enough include what is necessary for running the tests. The lane definition is:

```
desc "Run Unit Tests"
lane :unit_tests do
    scan(
        scheme: "myAppTests",
        devices: ["iPhone 11"]
    )
end
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
[16:20:32]: ▸ Linking myAppTests
[16:20:33]: ▸ Copying provisioning.plist
[16:20:33]: ▸ Copying GoogleService-Info.plist
[16:20:33]: ▸ Compiling SynchronizationViewController.xib
[16:20:33]: ▸ Processing Info.plist
[16:20:33]: ▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
[16:20:33]: Running Tests: ▸ Touching myAppTests.xctest (in target 'myAppTests' from project 'myApp')
[16:20:33]: ▸ Build Succeeded
[16:20:34]: ▸ Linking MYAPP
[16:20:34]: ▸ Running script 'SwiftLint'
[16:20:35]: ▸ Linking myAppTests
[16:20:35]: ▸ 2020-02-20 16:20:35.801 xcodebuild[42315:2308394]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
[16:20:35]: ▸ /Users/Jenkins.SVN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-gjylxkutiwwowsdxuadsovduecib/Logs/Test/Run-myAppTests-2020.02.20_16-19-59-+0000.xcresult/Staging/2_Test/Diagnostics/myAppTests-35F843CE-22FC-427A-B385-A9EF0F61E4B1/myAppTests-D3C6D752-F909-4965-BAB5-26194C7BB5D0/Session-myAppTests-2020-02-20_162035-s3sDH8.log
[16:20:35]: ▸ 2020-02-20 16:20:35.801 xcodebuild[42315:2306273] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (5D31D2AA-6061-40B3-943F-858AE0181E65) Beginning test session myAppTests-5D31D2AA-6061-40B3-943F-858AE0181E65 at 2020-02-20 16:20:35.801 with Xcode 11C505 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fa3f1a8e220> {
[16:20:35]: ▸       SimDevice: iPhone 11 (703948B3-684D-4E84-AFD4-34FFB522203D, iOS 13.3, Shutdown)
[16:20:35]: ▸ } (13.3 (17C45))
[16:20:37]: ▸ 2020-02-20 16:20:37.747 xcodebuild[42315:2306273] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (5D31D2AA-6061-40B3-943F-858AE0181E65) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
[16:20:40]: ▸ 2020-02-20 16:20:40.907 xcodebuild[42315:2306273] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 5.110 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
[16:20:40]: ▸ 2020-02-20 16:20:40.907 xcodebuild[42315:2306273] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
[16:20:40]: ▸ 2020-02-20 16:20:40.907 xcodebuild[42315:2306273] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 5.110 sec, +5.110 sec -- end
[16:20:41]: ▸ Testing failed:
[16:20:41]: ▸   myAppTests:
[16:20:41]: ▸       xctest (43228) encountered an error (Failed to load the test bundle. (Underlying error: The bundle “myAppTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources. dlopen_preflight(/Users/Jenkins.SVN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-gjylxkutiwwowsdxuadsovduecib/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myAppTests.xctest/myAppTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
[16:20:41]: ▸   Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib/libXCTestSwiftSupport.dylib
[16:20:41]: ▸   Reason: Incompatible library version: libXCTestSwiftSupport.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0))
[16:20:41]: ▸ ** TEST FAILED **
```

Podfile:

```
# define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.2'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

def default_pods
  pod 'MyAwesomePod'
end

target 'myApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  default_pods
end

target 'myAppTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  use_frameworks!
  default_pods
end

target 'myAppUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  use_frameworks!
  default_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_EXEC'] = '$(SRCROOT)/SWIFT_EXEC-no-coverage'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
      config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf-with-dsym'
      config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

`Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` has been set to `YES` across the test target and the application target.

[image: Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries = YES]

Comment: Do you have Build Settings > Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries set to `Yes`? Also could be something to do with podfile (missing `use_frameworks!` maybe?)

Comment: I've included my podfile. It has `use_frameworks!` in it. I've also set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES` in every conceivable place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be caused by using an incorrect version of the swift toolchain. Along with the latest toolchain installed via Xcode, we also had 4.2.4 and 5.1.2 installed. I believe the app was being published with 5.1.2, which satisfied the built target.

I resolved it by removing the unused swift toolchains. I could have also probably specified the toolchain to use in fastlane's `scan` and `gym` commands.